# Custom syntax in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm struggling to find out how to create a new syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 3 using the new **.sublime-syntax** style definition (most previous answers relate to old ways of doing it).

> As of Sublime Text Build 3084, a new syntax definition format has been added, with the .sublime-syntax extension.

I can find the:

- [syntax rules](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html)
- [scope naming rules](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html)
- [colour scheme rules](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html)

But I can't find the most basic piece of information detailing how these tie together!

I'm not trying to create a theme, or tweaking an existing syntax definition. I just want to create syntax highlighting to files with an extension I plan on using for my own purposes.

1. In the syntax definition I have to specify a scope (e.g. **scope: source.c**) but where does that scope file live? Or rather, where do I create my scope file, and how do I name it, so that it loads?
2. How do I know that my syntax file, and the scope file it uses, are loaded and applied successfully?
3. Are there any compile or refresh steps, or does everything automatically reload?

Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A full discussion of how to create a custom syntax is well outside the bounds of something as simple as a Stack Overflow answer. Also I think you're making your problem more complicated than it actually is (although creating a syntax is pretty complicated in general).

In order to walk you through the steps that you would take to create a custom syntax, here's an example.

To start with, create a file with the following contents and save it somewhere as `sample.ec`, and ***leave the file open***:

```
// This is a line comment
if (x == 2)
    y = 1
else
    z = 1
```

You'll notice that the syntax for this file is set to `Plain Text` (see the status line in the lower right), which is the default syntax for files that are unknown to Sublime.

Now, select `Tools > Developer > New Syntax...` from the menu. A buffer with the following will appear. Use `File > Save` to save the file; the location will default to your `User` package. The name you give it is not important, but make sure that the extension is `sublime-syntax`. In my example I'm calling my file `Sample.sublime-syntax`.

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
# See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
file_extensions:
  - ec
scope: source.example-c
contexts:
  main:
    # Strings begin and end with quotes, and use backslashes as an escape
    # character
    - match: '"'
      scope: punctuation.definition.string.begin.example-c
      push: double_quoted_string

    # Comments begin with a '//' and finish at the end of the line
    - match: '//'
      scope: punctuation.definition.comment.example-c
      push: line_comment

    # Keywords are if, else for and while.
    # Note that blackslashes don't need to be escaped within single quoted
    # strings in YAML. When using single quoted strings, only single quotes
    # need to be escaped: this is done by using two single quotes next to each
    # other.
    - match: '\b(if|else|for|while)\b'
      scope: keyword.control.example-c

    # Numbers
    - match: '\b(-)?[0-9.]+\b'
      scope: constant.numeric.example-c

  double_quoted_string:
    - meta_scope: string.quoted.double.example-c
    - match: '\\.'
      scope: constant.character.escape.example-c
    - match: '"'
      scope: punctuation.definition.string.end.example-c
      pop: true

  line_comment:
    - meta_scope: comment.line.example-c
    - match: $
      pop: true
```

Now open the Sublime Console with `View > Show Console` or press the associated key binding. You'll see that the last line in the console is this:

```
generating syntax summary
```

Leaving the console open, click in the syntax file and perform another save operation again without changing anything. The same line appears in the console again.

> 3. Are there any compile or refresh steps, or does everything automatically reload?

As seen here, every time you modify the syntax definition, the file is recompiled and the results are cached. So there are no compile steps (other than saving) and nothing you need to do in order to refresh anything.

Now lets turn our attention back to the sample file. It's still open, and the syntax still says that it's `Plain Text`.

Now close the file and re-open it again; a shortcut for this is to use `File > Open Recent > Reopen Closed File` or it's associated key binding.

Notice that now that the file is re-opened, there are several changes. Firstly, the syntax name in the bottom right side of the window says `Sample` (or whatever you named your `sublime-syntax` file above). For another, the contents of the file are now syntax highlighted.

The colors you see are dependent on the color scheme you use, but an example might look like this:

```c
// This is a line comment
if (x == 2)
    y = 1
else
    z = 1
```

> 2. How do I know that my syntax file, and the scope file it uses, are loaded and applied successfully?

You can see that the syntax file was compiled by the lack of an error message when you save your changes, and you can tell that it's applied by trying to use the syntax.

Here the syntax is being used automatically, but you'll find that if you check `View > Syntax` in the menu or click the current syntax name in the bottom right of the window, your syntax will appear there. Similarly there is now an entry in the command palette named `Set Syntax: Sample` (or whatever).

That leads us into your last question. If you go back to your `sublime-syntax` file, you'll see this at the top:

```yaml
# See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
file_extensions:
  - ec
scope: source.example-c
```

The first thing to note is that `file_extensions` includes `ec`, and our sample file is called `sample.ec`; thus this syntax applies to it automatically due to it's name.

Now switch into the `sample.ec` file, place the cursor somewhere in the buffer and use `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` or press the associated key.

The content of the popup that appears will vary depending on where in the file the cursor is located, but the common point is that the scope that appears always starts with `source.example-c`.

> 1. In the syntax definition I have to specify a scope (e.g. scope: source.c) but where does that scope file live? Or rather, where do I create my scope file, and how do I name it, so that it loads?

As seen here, there is no such thing as a "scope file"; the `sublime-syntax` file directly specifies the scope as part of the [syntax rules](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html), so it's the only file that you need to create in order to create a syntax. It may look like a filename, but it is not one.

The scopes that are applied in the syntax matching rules in the syntax need to coincide with the scopes in your color scheme in order to be syntax highlighted; that's why you should use the [scope naming rules](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html) to use the common set of scopes that all syntaxes share unless you're also planning to [make a color scheme](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html) to go along with your syntax, but unless you use the recommended scopes, your syntax won't work well with other color schemes and your color scheme won't work well for other syntaxes.

From this starting point you can modify the `sublime-syntax` file here in order to make it highlight files the way you want. That would include changing the base scope at the top, applying an appropriate extension, and then including all of the rules that match your language.

As mentioned above, creating the actual rules to match your file is the most complicated part of creating a syntax unless your file format is very simplistic. It's outside the scope of something that could be conveyed in a Stack Overflow answer, but the official documentation linked above gives you some information on it.

Apart from looking at existing syntax files to see how they're doing what they do, you can also ask more directed questions on the [Sublime forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/).

Answer (score 6):

I will shortly answer your questions, someone else can feel free to write a longer guide:

1. You put your syntax definitions inside a package: Select *Preferences > Browse Packages...* this should open your file explorer. There you can either create a new folder for a new package or use the *User* folder, which is the default user package. Inside that create a file *YourSyntax.sublime-syntax*.
2. You can open the ST console `` ctrl+` `` and it will output that the syntax is loaded and potential errors. You can also press *ctrl+shift+p* and write *Set Syntax: YourSyntax* in a buffer to directly see it.
3. You just need to save the file and it will reload the syntax definition.

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not tell me where I save the scope file, or how it links to the syntax definition file.

Comment: Oh I missed that question. There is no scope file, but the colorscheme file create scope selectors based on the scopes you define in your syntax definition. Therefore if you follow the conventions it will be highlighted correctly. However to enable some features (e.g. symbol movements with C-r, toggle comments with C-/) you will need to write a *.tmPreference file.