# Regex in Sublime Text 3 syntax file to capture everything after a word, including newlines

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I am writing a syntax definition for sublime text 3 where I try to capture all text that comes after the word END, including any newlines.
After reading the supported features of regex in sublime text 3: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kkos/oniguruma/5.9.6/doc/RE
i understand that i use (?m) to capture also the newline, 
and (?<=END) to capture everything after the word END.

however, I can't find the way to combine these two, so that i can capture all text in all lines after the word END.

edit: this is part of the syntax file:

```
contexts:
  main:
    - include: expressions

  expressions:
    - include: comments

  comments:
    - match: (?<=END)(.*)
      scope: comment.block
```

this works but only captures until the end of the line.

Comment: Sublime syntax matching is applied a line at a time, so you can't create just a regular expression that will match a word and all remaining content in the file. You need to create an additional `context` to do this. Can you provide a better example of what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Try `(?s)(?<=END).*`

Comment: This gives the error in sublime text 3: Error in regex: undefined group option in regex (?s)(?<=END).*

Comment: So, it is used in the grammar files, where Oniguruma is used, right? Then yes, lookbehind will not work, nor the modifiers.

Comment: It is used in the sublime-syntax file. The lookback does work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?si)(?<=END)(.*)
```

The first two modifiers indicate:

1. s: Treat all input as single line, matching newline characters with `.`
2. i: Case insensitive (remove this if you specifically want to search for capital "END")

Regex example: https://regex101.com/r/ToW4Ms/1

Comment: This also produces the error in sublime text 3: Error in regex: undefined group option in regex (?si)(?<=END)(.*)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your hint @OdatNurd, i read thru another answer of yours to a different question and that helped me find the solution: 
[Custom syntax in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781644/custom-syntax-in-sublime-text-3/49784249#49784249)

so this is how i did it, i added another context, and now it works!

```
contexts:
  main:
    - include: expressions

  expressions:
    - include: comments

  comments:
    - match: (?<=END)(.*)
      scope: comment.block
      push: end-comment

  end-comment:
    - meta_scope: comment.block 
    - match: (?m)(.*)
      pop: false
```